# Onclick event dynamically build and append div to an existing div (jquery or otherwise anything welcome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic-html

I have a div in the following format. 
1. How Can I add this to an existing div. Do I create a seperate html file and then add it using jquery? or Should I append this into a var and then append it to the div. Pls suggest a way to 1 append and create the div and then append it within another div(whose id i know)

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr><td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You could do it all as one string and then append. But it looks like there's some sort of repeated pattern, which makes me suspect (though not be entirely sure) that you could build a factory for these types of div instead, appending the individual components one at a time, or ultimately just using a big string like the original idea (but built within an iterator of some sort). Leaving this as a comment since I'm not actually providing a firm answer or code. ;-)

Comment: Sorry Greg, I am a newbie to js. Can you elaborate or direct me to a link for the string append part. The html looks repetitive but in reality it is not. The place where I mention rows with input might have variable td tags.

Comment: Thanks greg for the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this (using jQuery):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content" style="display: none;">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>text here and then some input tag
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
      <tr>text here and then some input tag
      </tr>
      <tr>text here and then some input tag
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
      <tr>text here and then some input tag
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="receiver1" style="background: #FF0000;"></div>
<div id="receiver2" style="background: #00FF00;"></div>
<div id="receiver3" style="background: #0000FF;"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    var theContent = $( "#content" ).html();
    $( "#receiver1" ).html( theContent );
    $( "#receiver2" ).html( theContent );
    $( "#receiver3" ).html( theContent );
});
```

You can view the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/3hm6N/1/

Of course, you can use the approach that Greg Pettit said. Another thing, I didn't saw it, but your table is missformated since the  tags should have `<td>`s or `<th>`s inside.

Comment: Hi David; Thanks for responding. I see your point, I need the store the html somewhere. How Can I store the html in the js. I understood the part where u append it. But most likely I will need to put the html div with unique id on to a var and then append it to the div of id receiver

Comment: @HaranMurthy - Hi! Yes, you can. You just need to create your HTML like a string and set it. Example: var myHtml = '<p>Text...</p>'; $( "#someId" ).html( myHtml );

Comment: @David- Got it thanks... Since I will need a unique id as well, I thought of adopting this procedure and modify it to my requirement. http://jsfiddle.net/yUfhL/ .Let me know what you think. It looks to be in line with the idea you suggested (that requires an upvote). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HaranMurthy - I think it is ok. I changed your code a little bit, just to use ids to reference the tags. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/yUfhL/77/ - Upvote and accept ;)